# Jobs storage engine that isn't mysql?

Tags: mysql, storage, job-scheduling

Im doing a lot of backend jobs on the site. Im using mysql for storing results of those jobs, as well as all the intermediary steps. The jobs are capable of completing with or without mysql being up. The problems is, if mysql craps out at any given time, the running job states get screwed up, and their results are useless (as they are encoded files in various locations).

Is there some kind of distributed storage engine I could use to store intermediate data and final results as a backup to mysql, so I could make sense of the resultant data, if mysql chooses to crap out.

Comment: Would it not be better to fix the problem with mysql?

Comment: The filesystem cannot be used to store these intermeditary files ?

Comment: I already write text log files, but these are for human readability mostly.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it sound like a problem with your whole architecture design, but if you're looking for alternate storage engines, there are many kinds to choose from. Here's a quick list of things that might be suitable, depending on exactly what your application is. Many more are are listed [here](http://nosql-database.org/).

CouchDb, Hadoop, MemcacheDB, Voldemort

Answer (score 0):

The nosql databases are intended to provide a high-availability distributed storae subsystem - however I've found the lack of relational capabilities rather restrictive.

sqlite is a simple in-process tool to use for relational databases.

I suppose a lot depends on what you are using to implement your logic in - and what it will talk to.

I must admit I'm a bit surprised that you seem to be having trouble with mysql's reliability - I've used it for some quite serious/high volume stuff and found it to be very stable - the only problems I've run into are:

1) when I ran an old version on top of md-raid - there was occasional corruption after large deletes

2) the table level locking problems problems updating large datasets in myisam (avoidable by using innodb)

You might want to consider continuing with mysql but using master-master replication and putting in a fault tolerant layer on top - e.g. [mysqlproxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy)

Comment: Biggest reason I wanted to do this is to disconnect the website that the site see, from backend data processing, which both run from the same database, using the same tables. Any issue with neither component, affects the other. So if there is a large spike in usage that causes any issue with mysql, it affects the processing thats happening, and vise versa.